# Unable to execute GUI application as a different user using `pkexec`

Tags: fedora, gnome, environment-variables, authentication, pkexec

I have created following policy file at `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/com.xyz.xyz.policy`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE policyconfig PUBLIC  "-//freedesktop//DTD PolicyKit Policy Configuration 1.0//EN"  "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/PolicyKit/1/policyconfig.dtd">     
    <policyconfig>   
        <vendor>XYZ Technologies Inc.</vendor>   
        <vendor_url>http://www.xyz.com</vendor_url>   
        <action id="org.xyz.policykit.pkexec.run-xyz">
            <description>Run XYZ</description>
            <message>Authentication is required to run XYZ</message>
            <defaults>
                <allow_any>no</allow_any>
                <allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
                <allow_active>auth_admin</allow_active>
            </defaults>
            <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/bin/xyz</annotate>
            <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui">TRUE</annotate>   
        </action> 
    </policyconfig>
```

and desktop file at `/usr/local/share/applications/xyz-gui-root.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name[en_in]=XYZ administrator (root)
Exec=pkexec xyz
Comment[en_IN]=Launches XYZ administrator
Name=XYZ administrator (root)
Comment=Launches XYZ administrator
Icon[en_IN]=/xyz/xyzroot.png
Icon=/xyz/xyzroot.png
```

When I search XYZ and run through `Activity->Search`, it doesn't show any activity, not even ask for password. But double clicking on `xyz-gui-root.desktop` file it works as expected with password authentication.

If I change

```
Exec=pkexec xyz
```

as

```
Exec=gnome-terminal -x pkexec xyz
```

it works fine with `Activity->Search` with authentication, but it opens a unwanted terminal.

What I am missing in above files? How can I avoid unwanted terminal to open with `gnome-terminal` entry? Is there any way to execute GUI application with authentication using `pkexec` or any other method like `consolehelper`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete answer for my question is [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/721075/392252). In short:

1) Create a shell script as /usr/local/bin/foo.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
pkexec "/usr/sbin/foo" "$@"
```

2) Give executable permission to above script:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/foo.sh
```

3) If you are using .desktop file, change Exec value as:

```
Exec=/usr/local/bin/foo.sh
```

4) Make sure that your policy file in /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/ has following entry to allow GUI:

```
<annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui">TRUE</annotate>
```

Thats it!

Comment: NON, this does not cause the password neither to be accepted nor not requested.